# Temporary access to application with Spring Security and LDAP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem. I have a web application written in Java based on Spring with authentication based on Spring Security and Active Directory and LDAP under the hood. I need to prepare a registration functionality in the application. User should be able to register and log in just after registration. The problem is that even if we add the registering user to appropriate LDAP group he/she has to wait until the change will propagate over every node which can take few hours. I thought about giving temporary access someway. For 24 hours i.e. This should be enough to propagate changes in LDAP. I'm searching possible solutions for this. I thought about keeping the temporary access in a database and write custom login functionality based on both LDAP and database. But maybe there is simpler solution which I do not know. Any ideas?

Comment: You could maybe do an OAUTH2 authentication temporarily alongwith the registration form - http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/